# List current HAProxy appsession keys

Tags: haproxy, sticky-sessions

Please consider this HAProxy configuration with sticky sessions using JSESSIONID

```
defaults
    timeout server 5m

frontend http-in
    bind *:80
    default_backend servers

backend servers
    option httpchk OPTIONS /
    option forwardfor
    option http-server-close
    appsession JSESSIONID len 52 timeout 30m
    server ut1 192.168.123.101:8080 minconn 100 maxconn 8000 check inter 5000
    server ut2 192.168.123.102:8080 minconn 100 maxconn 8000 check inter 5000
```

Some of the sessions suddenly switch server, while they are supposed to be sticky. I'd like to inspect the session ids known to HAProxy. Is there a command I can use to list the current appsession keys the HAProxy has in memory?